# Solr - How to boost score for early matches?

Tags: solr

How can I boost the score for documents in which my query matches a particular field earlier. For example, searching for "super man" should give "super man returns" a higher score than "there is my super man". Is this possible?

Comment: Uh, store the first few words explicitly in another field, and boost matches on this field.

Comment: The problem there is that the size of the query can vary from say 3 characters to say 100 characters, and so determining how many words/chars to index separately can be difficult.

Comment: Secondly, suppose i index the first 25 characters, and one record has "my super man blah.." and another record has "super man returns blah.." - both will match the query "super man" and both will be boosted when i boost this secondary field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it myself after reading a LOT about this online. What specifically helped me was a reply on nabble which goes like (I used dismax, so explaining that here):

- Create a separate field named say 'nameString' which stores the value as `"_START_ <actual data>"`
- Change the search query to `"_START_ <actual query>"`
- Add the new field `nameString` as one of the fields to look in in the query fields param (qf)
- While searching use the parameter pf (phrase field) as the new field `nameString` with a phrase slop of 1 or 2 (lower values would mean stricter searching)

Your final query params will be something like:

```
q=_START_ <actual query>
defType=dismax
qf=name nameString /* look in name field as well as nameString field */
pf=nameString /* phrase field in nameString */
ps=2 /* phrase slop */
```

Comment: Could you please explain it in detail?

Comment: for ex: if you have 2 records with field data "spider man returns" and "the amazing spider man" - both of them will rank equally when you search for "spider man" - The above strategy stores them as "_START_ spider man returns" and "_START_ the amazing spider man" - And the search query is modified to be "_START_ spider man" instead of just "spider man" - This way "_START_ spider man returns" scores more over the other record as it more closely matches the search query.

Comment: So we need to add START before every names?

Comment: Yes, but not in the original field containing the names. We keep the original name fields unaltered and create a separate field (just for searching, not for displaying) in the index, where we'll be storing the names as "START <name value>"

Comment: By the way, I did this waaay back in 2012 when it was still Solr. 3.5.x or so. Now Solr is in version 5 and there probably is a cleaner and easier way to achieve this now.

Comment: Is there any specific analyzer need while indexing for this new filed?

Answer (score 2):

Check for options @ [Ranking-based-on-term-position](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Ranking-based-on-term-position-td979271.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But i solved it today by using the approach i've outlined in my answer.

Comment: But this is not going to work if the words do not occur at the very start. May want to check out payloads as well where u can add index time suggestions as laid down in the second option.

Comment: Will check that out as well. However, the current solution can be made to work to a large extent by fine tuning the ps parameter to make it more lenient. I currently use 2 (dist between 2 terms in the pf) and it seems to be working quite well for my medium sized data set (1000s of records, greatly varying in content). Will check out your point and let you know if it helped.