# SOLR Results Ranking

Tags: solr, ranking

Using 6.0.1 SOLR.
 Have got a type declaration:

```
 <fieldType name="customy_icu" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
         <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.ICUTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="1" max="100"/>
            <filter class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="20"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
         </analyzer>
         <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.ICUTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="1" max="100"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
         </analyzer>
      </fieldType>
```

customy_icu is used for storing text data at hebrew lang (word are reading/writing) from right to left.

When query is "מי פנים"
I have got the result in incorrect order, product_3351 is higher (more relevant) than product  product_3407, but should be vice versa.
Here is debug:

```
 <str name="product_3351">
2.711071 = sum of:
  2.711071 = max of:
    0.12766865 = weight(meta_keyword:"מי פנים" in 882) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:
      0.12766865 = score(doc=882,freq=1.0), product of:
        0.05998979 = queryWeight, product of:
          8.5126915 = idf(), sum of:
            4.7235003 = idf(docFreq=21, docCount=910)
            3.7891912 = idf(docFreq=55, docCount=910)
          0.0070471005 = queryNorm
        2.1281729 = fieldWeight in 882, product of:
          1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
            1.0 = phraseFreq=1.0
          8.5126915 = idf(), sum of:
            4.7235003 = idf(docFreq=21, docCount=910)
            3.7891912 = idf(docFreq=55, docCount=910)
          0.25 = fieldNorm(doc=882)
    2.711071 = weight(name:"מי פנים" in 882) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:
      2.711071 = score(doc=882,freq=1.0), product of:
        0.6178363 = queryWeight, product of:
          9.99 = boost
          8.776017 = idf(), sum of:
            4.8417873 = idf(docFreq=22, docCount=1071)
            3.93423 = idf(docFreq=56, docCount=1071)
          0.0070471005 = queryNorm
        4.3880086 = fieldWeight in 882, product of:
          1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
            1.0 = phraseFreq=1.0
          8.776017 = idf(), sum of:
            4.8417873 = idf(docFreq=22, docCount=1071)
            3.93423 = idf(docFreq=56, docCount=1071)
          0.5 = fieldNorm(doc=882)
</str>
```

and

```
  <str name="product_3407">
2.711071 = sum of:
  2.711071 = max of:
    2.711071 = weight(name:"מי פנים" in 919) [ClassicSimilarity], result of:
      2.711071 = score(doc=919,freq=1.0), product of:
        0.6178363 = queryWeight, product of:
          9.99 = boost
          8.776017 = idf(), sum of:
            4.8417873 = idf(docFreq=22, docCount=1071)
            3.93423 = idf(docFreq=56, docCount=1071)
          0.0070471005 = queryNorm
        4.3880086 = fieldWeight in 919, product of:
          1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
            1.0 = phraseFreq=1.0
          8.776017 = idf(), sum of:
            4.8417873 = idf(docFreq=22, docCount=1071)
            3.93423 = idf(docFreq=56, docCount=1071)
          0.5 = fieldNorm(doc=919)
</str>
```

The product 3351 has name field value:
סאבליים סופט מי פנים
And product 3407  has name field value:
 מי פנים מיסלרים

http://screencast.com/t/2iBwLQqu

How I can boost 3407 product it become higher in result list ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why is it more relevant? If it's just because of your own knowledge, you can use the query elevation component to "stick" a document at the top for a certain query.

Comment: More relevant because we expect the docs where search phrase encounters at start of indexed fields should be higher in search results. We use dismax engine and boost:           aw_shopbybrand_brand^9.00 body_formulation body_scent face_care_formulation hair_type meta_keyword name^9.99 parfum_size parfum_type scent_type shade_optiond size skin_problam skin_type sku^9.00 soap_size spf test_color title short_content post_content label content

Comment: Does "Stick" applicable for concrete queries? But if we don't know what  queries would be typed, how we can specify them a priori?

Comment: Yes, elevation works for specific queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a specific query where you want to boost a document to the top of the result set, irrelevant of its own score, use the [Query Elevation Component](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Query+Elevation+Component).

There is no automagic boosting for "appears earlier in the document", but there's a few ways to work around it. See [How to boost scores for early matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070016/solr-how-to-boost-score-for-early-matches) for a couple of possible solutions.

"Relevancy" is a fluent term, and you have to implement the kind of scoring that you feel is suitable for your application outside of the standard rules. The debugQuery you've included shows that the documents are scored identically on relevancy by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use elevate.xml file to set particular document to appear top in the resultset for specific serachterm.

example :

```
<elevate>
<query text ="מי פנים">
<doc id="your_product_ID" />
</query>
```