# Free natural text search in SOLR Query and SCORE

Tags: solr

I have an application that accept free text searchs for users. Suppose an user writes "one two three" in a html input text, so my search URI is ".../solr/my_index/select?q=expressions:(one two three)...".

Documents are described in schema as follows:

```
<field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="expressions" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

In "my_index" I have two documents indexed:

id:"1", expressions: ["seven one two three four five", "seven eight seven", "two six nine six"]

id:"2", expressions: ["one", "one two", "one two four", "four one two one"]

The result of the query is that document id=2 have bigger score because of more matches of the words "one" and "two". But I have more specific requirements: the SCORE must consider not match count, but "similarity in the search phrase". So, because the document id=1 has a value "seven one two three four five", with the "..one two three..." substring inside the value, and this is very similar to the phrase written by the user, document id=1 must have the bigger SCORE.

Can this be done? I am very new to SOLR/Lucene, so I don't know if I need to use an specific query parser, build a custom one...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So basically your problems boils down to how to boost a document based on how early the match is. In Lucene there is support for [SpanFirst](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanFirstQuery.html) query which gives this feature. Although there is an open ticket in [Solr Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3925) regarding adding support for SpanFirst to Solr but I have not seen anything regarding this yet implemented. However you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070016/solr-how-to-boost-score-for-early-matches) for help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with minimum match `mm` parameter with dismax/edismax Query Parser.

`mm` it indicates minimum number of clauses that must match in a query

solr request url with `mm` paramter.

Ex:

```
.../solr/my_index/select?q=expressions:(one two three)&defType=dismax&mm=3...
```