# relevance by keyword solr

Tags: sorting, solr, drupal-7, relevance, solr5

How can we sort the results of a query according to the position of the keyword?

I start the search only on the field Label

when I have

1. solr search query **titi**
2. **titi** test tilte
3. toto **titi** tata

what parameter should we put in place to have this order back?

1. **titi** test tilte
2. toto **titi** tata
3. solr search query **titi**

I use Drupal for connect and send query to solr.

Comment: As far as I know; you can't. The term's position isn't used for scoring (except for phrase queries). You'll probably have to write a custom function or scorer to achieve that. An "easy" way could be to follow [the payload tutorial](https://lucidworks.com/2009/08/05/getting-started-with-payloads/) from lucidworks, which uses payloads attached to each term to rank the importance of that term. You might be able to skip the payload and just use the position directly as well..

Comment: @MatsLindh I forgot to specify I already run the search on the label fields only

Comment: I'm not sure how that would change anything.

Answer (score 0):

If your domain is very contained and you know for example the size of the label you expect you can obtain something close to what you want with copy fields and the dismax query parser.
Specifically you could build N "copyfields" in this way :

```html
<field name="label" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="label_3" type="text_first_3" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="label_5" type="text_first_5" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
...
<fieldType name="text_first_3" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LimitTokenPositionFilterFactory"             maxTokenPosition="3" consumeAllTokens="false" />
</analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

<fieldType name="text_first_5" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LimitTokenPositionFilterFactory"             maxTokenPosition="5" consumeAllTokens="false" />
</analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
...
<copyField source="label" dest="label_3"/>
<copyField source="label" dest="label_5"/>
```

This works thanks to the limit token position filter[1].
Then you can specify a different boost with the edismax :

qf="label_3^5 label_5^2 label"

The problem is also discussed here [2].

An alternative approach is mentioned here[3].

[1] https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-LimitTokenPositionFilter

[2] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3925

[3] [Solr - How to boost score for early matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070016/solr-how-to-boost-score-for-early-matches)